# Why does this stl function return this double value?

Tags: stl, c++builder, stringstream

The following assertion fails in RAD Studio 2010 (and incidentally would succeed in Visual Studio 2010):

```
double              d1 = 0.0104;
double              d2 = 0.0;
std::istringstream  ss("0.0104");
ss >> d2;
assert(d1 == d2);
```

This surprised me a little. I traced down into the extraction operator to see what was happening, got as far as `dinkumware/xlocnum`, and couldn't trace any further.

Can anyone tell me why `__Stodx(... "0.0104")` returns a value that's marginally different from a double initialized to `0.0104`?

(I know that certain values can't be represented exactly in binary. What I want to know is why the resultant doubles contain different values so that I can understand it.)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please read the link provided in answer?

Comment: Yes. I am aware of this problem ("I know that certain values can't be represented exactly in binary ..."), but I want to know what /exactly/ is going on in this case, with this compiler. I want to know what happens in the referenced stod() that's different from when a double gets initialized.

Comment: difference only in computational nature of strtod - for example http://www.koders.com/c/fidF56FB8FFAA70E9B41916B9A994E82C314E250DFB.aspx?s=strtod#L32 .

Comment: That's what I expect too, Sergey. I'm hoping someone with deep knowledge of the Embarcadero compiler/libraries can tell me more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dear Me: The compiler and library use different methods to convert strings to doubles, and without access to the compiler source, nobody is going to be able to tell you how those methods differ.

Sorry,
Me

Answer (score 2):

Here the [answer](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/newbie.html#faq-29.17) to this question.

> [29.17] Why doesn't my floating-point comparison work?
>
> Because floating point arithmetic is different from real number
>   arithmetic.
>
> Bottom line: Never use == to compare two floating point numbers.

Here the answer on "why the resultant doubles contain different values"

1. d1 is exact constant representation provided by compiler
2. d2 is computed during conversion (see example of [strtod](http://www.koders.com/c/fidF56FB8FFAA70E9B41916B9A994E82C314E250DFB.aspx?s=strtod#L32)), so it can be some rounding errors during floating-point calculation as described [here](http://floating-point-gui.de/) and [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Apologies, but I can't accept this answer. It's just not correct. The problem isn't that strtod can have rounding errors, and d1 is /not/ "exact constant representation". It is the representation provided by whatever method the compiler uses to convert strings to doubles, which is apparently different than the method used by dinkumware. I think the right answer to my question looks something like: "the compiler and library use different methods to convert strings to doubles, and without access to the compiler source, nobody is going to be able to tell you how those methods differ."